# Can I put wireless activity on a separate network on the one router?

Tags: networking, dhcp, wifi, adsl

We have a foreign delegation coming in next week. Some of them will be IT-savvy. We don't want them wandering through our network. We have a wired network and a wireless network both going through the one ADSL router.

Can I set up the wireless user to be on a separate network? Is it still possible for the wired and wireless groups to connect to the internet?

Comment: Do you have a managed switch that lets you do VLANs?

Comment: Not sure. I have a 'iConnectAccess624w'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use my WRT54G with DD-WRT firmware to achieve this - you are able to create multiple 'virtual' interfaces with different subnets and rules; thus separating the networks and ensuring that traffic does not leak over to the other.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is give them access to the internet and you aren't too many of them, the easiest solution is to buy a consumer-grade DSL router and plug it into the DMZ or outside the firewall.